# How to open Parity database from javascript (how to open column families)?

Tags: parity, database, query

I am trying to connect to Parity database at `var dbPath = 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Parity\\Ethereum\\chains\\ethereum\\db\\906a34e69aec8c0d\\overlayrecent\\db'` form javascript using npm module `level-rocksdb` in this way:

```
var level = require('level-rocksdb');
var db = level(databasePath);
```

But I am getting error:

```
(node:22916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: OpenError: Invalid argument: You have to open all column families. Column families not opened: col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
    at C:...project\node_modules\levelup\lib\levelup.js:87:23
    at C:...project\node_modules\abstract-leveldown\abstract-leveldown.js:41:14
    at C:...project\node_modules\deferred-leveldown\deferred-leveldown.js:20:21
    at C:...project\node_modules\abstract-leveldown\abstract-leveldown.js:41:14
    at C:...project\node_modules\abstract-leveldown\abstract-leveldown.js:41:14
(node:22916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22916) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How should I pass options to level constructor to open column families? Function signature is const db = level(location[, options[, callback]]).